# How do I create a fictional world map with a globe locator in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, globe

I'm in the process of mapping out a fictional planet, and I also hope to utilise the Globe Builder plugin to create some locator maps for certain locations of note.

For ease I just decided that my planet would be the same size as Earth; and so to begin with I loaded in a world map (of earth), dissolved all features and then used a geometry generator of "bounds($geometry)" to visualise my boundary to work within. [image: See this image]

My hope was that I could use this boundary as the background colour for my planet and slowly build features on top of it. However, when I use the Globe Builder plug-in (loading in only graticules), this bounding box feature does not render on the globe. As you can see below:

[image]